# Non deterministic fields getting recalculated between showing, counting, and saving a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, non-deterministic

We have a `uuid` `udf` :

```
import java.util.UUID
val idUdf = udf(() => idgen.incrementAndGet.toString + "_" + UUID.randomUUID)
spark.udf.register("idgen", idUdf)
```

An issue being faced is that when running `count`, or `show` or `write` each of those end up with a *different* value of the `udf` result.

```
    df.count()             // generates a UUID for each row
    df.show()              // regenerates a UUID for each row
    df.write.parquet(path) // .. you get the picture ..
```

What approaches might be taken to retain a single `uuid` result for a given row?   The first thought would be to invoke a remote `Key-Value` store using some unique combination of other *stable* fields within each column.  That is of course expensive both due to the lookup-per-row and the configuration and maintenance of the remote `KV Store`.  Are there other mechanisms to achieve stability for these unique ID columns?

Comment: If the other questions treat on similar topics, it is entirely not evident from their titles. This question identifies a specific well defined scenario along with precise keywords for search.  Well at least googlers can get to the other answers (if useful) via a couple of hops proxied by this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your udf as nondeterministic by calling:

```
val idUdf = udf(() => idgen.incrementAndGet.toString + "_" + UUID.randomUUID)
    .asNondeterministic()
```

This will evaluate your udf just once and keep the result in the RDD

Comment: well better luck for next time around. spent couple of hours refactoring to save the RDD then read it back as a functional but v ugly workaround

Comment: We’ve all been there :-)